# Xcode - Dynamic height only with top label

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I am stuck with trying to only set dynamic height for the top label in the image provided. I have tried multiple things but I always end up with the row overlapping the content. Any help would be appreciated. I am using AutoLayout with Swift.

[image: xcode_dynamic_height_top_label]

UPDATE:

Here are the current constraints that I have:

[image: image2]
[image: image3]

I have the following code in my viewDidLoad for the view controller:

```
notificationsTable.estimatedRowHeight = 85.0
notificationsTable.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

Comment: please show your constraints and your desired output what actually you want to achieve ?

Comment: have you added constraint ye in this cell?

Comment: I have updated my post.

Comment: I want to mention I am targeting iOS 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this:

Image with long text:
[image]

Short text:
[image]

Image constraint:

[image]

Dynamic Label Constraint:

[image]

Normal text constraint:

[image]

Hope this help

Comment: This almost works, my image is cutting off just a bit, what needs to be adjusted? Also I don't want my image to stretch.

Comment: You can try setting Image Content Mode to Aspect Fit or Aspect Fill

Comment: No I don't mean that, I mean the row is clipping the bottom of the image and causing the image to overlap the next row when there is only one line of text.

Comment: Change bottom space of Notification Date to SuperView from = to >=

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/J4EvZ - Image Constraints. Everything is working fine except the overlap. I have >= for bottom space.

Comment: Add image view bottom constraint to supperView (in this case is 8), and set priority is High (750)

Comment: Thank you, that has fixed the image overlapping but now the text does not go to the next line and notification date is missing. Here is a photo.

http://imgur.com/a/SJMSl

Comment: I was able to get your method working if I changed the image view bottom constraint to >= instead of =  Also I had to set my text to nil inside of cellAtRowPath then set the text for each cell afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple method:

```
 func heightForView(_ text:String, width:CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    let label:UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping
    label.text = text
    label.sizeToFit()
    return label.frame.height
}

notificationsTable.rowHeight = heightForView(yourText, width: yourCGFloatWidth)
```